# Magento 1.9 Custom extension not displaying block in product view

Tags: magento-1.9, product, extensions, custom-extension

I have been trying to display a custom template in the product view page in a simple extension but it only works for some references: **product.info.additional, product.info.extrahint, product.tooltip and product.info.addtocart**.

My `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/productest.xml` looks like this. I m trying to display a simple text now but to no success:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="core/text" name="core-text"><action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<div>Souh</div>]]></text></action></block>
    </reference>

  </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

I have also echoed the block names that are used in the product page:

```
Array
(
    [0] => product.info.media
    [1] => alert.urls
    [2] => product.info.upsell
    [3] => product.info.additional
    [4] => product.description
    [5] => product.attributes
    [6] => catalog.product.related
    [7] => product.info.addto
    [8] => product.info.sharing
    [9] => product.info.addtocart
    [10] => product.info.extrahint
    [11] => product.info.options.wrapper
    [12] => product.info.options.wrapper.bottom
    [13] => product.info.container1
    [15] => product.info.additional.recurring.schedule
    [16] => product.reviews
    [17] => product.info.simple
    [18] => product.info.availability
)
```

I don't understand why not all of them can be extended/referenced when they all appear to be called in the product page.

Thank you in advance for your help.